# What if there is only Bid and no Ask?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, shares, nse-india, bse-india

Today, I have bought shares of one company at morning and it was showing inflation where both both Ask and Bid was rotating but later, till afternoon, only Bid was rising and Ask it was 0.
When this situation occur, the market price of company was stagnant. A huge volume was participating in Bid but then also price of share stopped at one value.
Can you answer me why this happened. I think, the reason is that there was no Ask. But I doubt that because is it possible that volume is in millions and only Bid is there with 0 Ask.
I am new in this, so correct me if I mistaken somewhere.

Comment: This should help: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bid-and-ask.asp